# Azure Mobile App Service metadata columns (deleted ) be set using SyncTables

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I'm using the Azure Mobile App Service soft delete and incremental sync features. I set the deleted flag as false on the client side by doing something like this for the Foo entity and then tried to retrieve it :

```
1) foo.deleted = false;
2) Client.GetSyncTable<Foo>().Update(foo);
3) Client.GetSyncTable<Foo>().Where(w => w.id == "xxx" && w.deleted == false).ToListAsync(); 
//The above step 3 doesn't seem to return any results.
4) Client.GetSyncTable<Foo>().Where(w => w.id == "xxx").ToListAsync(); //This returns a result;
```

All the above steps as I understand are happening against the offline table.

I was just curious to know what might be happening behind the scenes. I do know that there's a DeleteAsync method available but I just wanted to understand what causes step 3 to not return any results but step 4 does return a result.

Can't the metadata column deleted be manipulated on the client side ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the code on GitHub - https://github.com/azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client

Short version, When you do a ...Where(something), it creates a SQL query, but does not execute it.  When you actually request results (via .ToListAsync(), for example), then it executes the query, converts the results and returns them to you.  This allows you to build complex LINQ expressions that are then turned into SQL queries in the most efficient manner possible.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your response. The missing ToListAsync() was a typo. Sorry about that. (Your blog is awesome btw!!)
My question is when I do
1) foo.deleted = false;
2) Client.GetSyncTable<Foo>().UpdateAsync(foo);
//The below step 3 returns 0 records
3) Client.GetSyncTable<Foo>().Where(w => w.id == "xxx" && w.deleted == false).ToListAsync(); 
// But step 4 returns a result;
4) Client.GetSyncTable<Foo>().Where(w => w.id == "xxx").ToListAsync(); 

In short does setting, 
 foo.deleted = true and then executing UpdateAsync(foo) the same as doing DeleteAsync(foo) ??